# Mikeal's NodeJS Request modify body before piping

Tags: node.js, express, request

I'm using [mikeal's](https://github.com/mikeal) awesome [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module for NodeJS. I'm also using it with [express](http://expressjs.com) where I'm proxying a call to the API for getting around CORS issues for older browsers:

```
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
  var matches = request.url.match(/^\/API_ENDPOINT\/(.*)/),
      method = request.method.toLowerCase(),
      url;

  if (matches) {
    url = 'http://myapi.com' + matches[0];

    return request.pipe(req[method](url)).pipe(response);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Is there a way I can modify the body before I pipe the `request`'s response back to `express`?

Answer (score 12):

Based on this answer: [Change response body before outputting in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120798/change-response-body-before-outputting-in-node-js) I made a working example that I use on my own app:

```
app.get("/example", function (req, resp) {
  var write = concat(function(response) {
    // Here you can modify the body
    // As an example I am replacing . with spaces
    if (response != undefined) {
      response = response.toString().replace(/\./g, " ");
    }
    resp.end(response);
  });

  request.get(requestUrl)
      .on('response',
        function (response) {
          //Here you can modify the headers
          resp.writeHead(response.statusCode, response.headers);
        }
      ).pipe(write);
});
```

Any improvements will be welcome, hope it helps!

Comment: Nice, I'll try this out.

Comment: Worked for me. I didn't need the writeHead line for some reason. Seems to work the same with or without.

Comment: Can I also get the body of the response?

Comment: concat is not defined, also resp in "resp.end" isn't defined

Comment: @RolandoCorratgeNieves @mis3590712 you need to install `concat-stream` before.

Comment: For completeness sake: request also accepts a `callback(err,msg,body)`-option, which makes the use of `concat-stream` obsolete for this example.
You should also note that this solution (even though making a call to `pipe()`) will download the complete response into memory, then perform the replacement and then push out the response. 

With regards to performance @Pickels answer is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use a [transform stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform). After some googling I found the following [blog post](http://nicolashery.com/parse-data-files-using-nodejs-streams).

Comment: This was very helpful but it didn't get me far. I was able to use a transform to convert the data but then I ran across write issues in the stream :(